# Adding Animation to Inputfield and save the transform

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to add a simple search animation to my input field in my unity UI.
[image: search-InputField]

This is my InputField and the idea is, when I select it, it should expand slowly, and when I deselect it, it should shrink back to its normal form.

[image: RectTransfrom Component]

This is the rect Transform Component of this inputfield. I added to the input field and Event Trigger Component and an Animator. I created two Animations called SearchAnimation and DeselectAnimation and added them to my AnimationController called 'SearchController'.
This is how I designed my SearchController:
[image: AnimationController]
I set the Transitions between the defaultState and SearchAnimation to be listening to the SelectBool and DeselectBool (the name already describes its purpose).

Then I added the following script to my input Field so that those two booleans will be set accordingly to the event trigger:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OnClickScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    public void OnSelect()
    {
        anim.SetBool("SelectBool", true);
        anim.SetBool("DeselectBool", false);
        GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(450, 50);
        GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.Set(-275, 0, 0);

    }

    public void OnDeselect()
    {
        anim.SetBool("DeselectBool", true);
        anim.SetBool("SelectBool", false);
        GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(200, 50);
        GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.Set(-130, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

But after the animation is played the inputfield is set back to its inital size and location. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy way**:

Create one more clips. The clip is made of only one key which is the `Size Delta` of the SelectedState. Then make this clip the animation clip of the state.

I put my test project [here](https://github.com/ming060/InputFieldExpandAnimExample).

[image: Selected State Animation Example]

With above approach, once you want to change the size of default state and selected state, you will have to change all four animation clips manually.

**Hard way**

Using [AnimationClip.SetCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SetCurve.html) to create animation from the script. With this approach, you can create more maintainable animations. But it's not easy to create complex animations with scripts.

**Suggestions**:

Using Pivot:

In the script, you are changing local position to prevent the input field moving up. Instead of changing the local position value, you can set the pivot Y to 1 if you want the input field to expand downward.

[image]

Using trigger:

Instead of using two `bool` variables, you can simply use one `Trigger` to trigger the animation start and move to next state.

[image]

Comment: didn't think of giving the selected state another animtation, that was simple